# How to add new item in SharePoint Online top ribbon using JavaScript/Powershell/JQuery?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, powershell, jquery, top-link-bar

I want to know that is it possible to add new icon before the Notification icon and call some JavaScript stuffs in SharePoint Online using JavaScript?

[image]

If yes then how we can achieve it using JavaScript or JQuery or Powershell?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code in Script Editor:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 //Define new links
  var newLinks = "<li class='ms-core-suiteLink'> \
   <a class='ms-core-suiteLink-a' href='http://extranet.crescent.com'>Extranet</a> \
   </li> \
   <li class='ms-core-suiteLink'> \
   <a class='ms-core-suiteLink-a' href='http://support.crescent.com'>Customer Support</a> \
   </li> ";

  $('.ms-core-deltaSuiteLinks').prepend(newLinks);
  alert('works');
  });

</script>
```

Hope it works for you.

Reference Link: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/09/how-to-add-link-to-sharepoint-2013-suite-bar.html

Comment: While link may answer the question, but please include some essential content of the link in the answer because once the link is broken the answer become useless. Thanks

Comment: Your answer is for SharePoint 2013 On-Prem, there is a vast change in SP-Online html.

Comment: @Akash Thanks for giving suggestion. Check updated answer